# Concatenate variables and create MD5

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Using JMeter, I would like to take values from CSV file, concatenate the values and do a MD5 hash on them and then send the value as part of HTTP request using HTTP Request Sampler.

I tried the following but did not get the correct result:

1. created CSV Data Set Config and added the variables csvVal1,csvVal2,csvVal3;
2. in the jp@gc-Dummy Sampler i added the following:

   ```
   ${__MD5(${csvval1}+${csvval2}+${csvval3})}
   ```

This did not work, what is the right way?

Comment: ...Sorry for necroposting but there is no need in any additional signs for variables concatenation in function call. I.e. `${__MD5(${csvval1}${csvval2}${csvval3})}` will work.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using BeanShell Preporcessor and used the following script

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

String val1 = vars.get("csv_val1");
String val2 = vars.get("csv_val2");
String val3 = vars.get("csv_val3");

String totalString = val1+val2+val3;

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] md5hash = new byte[32];
md.update(totalString.getBytes("utf-8"), 0, totalString.length());
md5hash = md.digest();

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i=0;i<md5hash.length;i++) {
    String sval = Integer.toHexString((int) md5hash[i] & 0xFF);
    if(sval.length()== 1)
    {
        sval = "0"+sval;
    }
                sb.append(sval);
}   

log.info("tktest: "+ sb);

vars.putObject("MD5Signature", sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a new function `__digest`, currently in [nightly builds](https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/dist/)

[image]
In your case to save in MD5Signature variable the result of 3 variable use the following:

```
${__digest(MD5,${csv_val1}${csv_val2}${csv_val3},,,MD5Signature)}
```